# Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'VMware.VumAutomation.Types.Patch' required by parameter 'IncludePatch'

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to programatically get the latest VMware tools update and add it to a  new baseline in powershell, if the baseline already exists i want to include in that baseline, but i keep getting this error:

> Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type
> 'VMware.VumAutomation.Types.Patch' required by parameter
> 'IncludePatch'

This is the code:

```
$baseline = Get-PatchBaseline -Name $baseline_name
    # get the last version of vmware tools
    $latest_tools = Get-Patch | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*VMware Tools*"}| Sort-Object -Property Version | Select-Object -Last 1
    $patches = Get-Patch -Server $server -Before $before_date
    
    # This line of code fails:
    $all_patches = $patches, $latest_tools
  

    # If the baseline was not found make a new one
    if (-not $baseline){
     
        Download-Patch

        $baseline = New-PatchBaseline -Server $server -Name $baseline_name -Static -IncludePatch $all_patches
        
    }
    else {
        Set-PatchBaseline -Baseline $baseline -IncludePatch $all_patches

    }
```

Executing this code directly in powershell it works, using a script that calls this code it doesn't, it throws the error.

What i tried:

```
$all_patches = @($patches, $latest_tools)
$patches = $patches, $latest_tools
$patches += $latest_tools
$patches.Add($latest_tools)
```

How to make it work?

[image: Var types for patches & latest_tools]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accidentally creating a *jagged* array, whereas you need a *flat* one (a single-dimensional array whose elements aren't arrays themselves).

There are several ways to solve this, but a simple and efficient one is:

```
$all_patches = [array] $patches + $latest_tools
```

That is:

- Use the [`+`operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arithmetic_Operators)...
- ... with an *array* as the LHS (which the `[array]` cast ensures) in order to produce a flat array that is the *concatenation* of the LHS array and the RHS, which works with both a scalar and an array RHS (in the latter case, the RHS array's *elements* are appended)

Note that - given that arrays are fixed-size data structures - such an operation invariably creates a *new* array.

---

Another way of ensuring that the LHS is an array is to use `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--):

```
$all_patches = @($patches) + $latest_tools
```

This is more concise, and is likely good enough in most cases, but it's worth pointing out that if `$patches` already *is* an array, `@(...)` causes it to be *enumerated* and then collected in a *new* array (invariably of type `[object[]]`), which the `[array]` cast does *not* do.